# Converting cv::Mat rotation matrix to quaternion

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to convert a cv::Mat rotation matrix to a quaternion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358188/converting-cv::mat-rotation-matrix-to-quaternion/) by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2020-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-07-28**:
You tagged `roscpp` so I'd assume you are using CPP... is that right? It would likely help to say what datatype you have a rotation matrix as. For example, the answer you're looking for will depend on if you have an `Eigen::Affine3d` vs a `tf2::Matrix3x3` vs something else.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-07-28**:
If you do have a `tf2::Matrix3x3` you could use [the `getRotation` method](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Matrix3x3.html#ab65659037e9db4fa754863353aa1f663)

**Comment by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) on 2020-07-28**:
In fact, I have a cv::Mat object and I want to convert it to a quaternion to populate a geometry_msgs/Pose message.

**Comment by [EDU4RDO-SH](https://answers.ros.org/users/49962/edu4rdo-sh/) on 2020-07-28**:
I'll try! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that case, personally, I'd lean towards constructing a `tf2::Matrix3x3` from the `cv::Mat`. Then you can construct a `tf2::Transform` from the `Matrix3x3`, and then use `tf2::toMsg` to convert to a `geometry_msgs/Pose` directly. You could also call `getRotation` as I mentioned earlier to get a Quaternion directly, and then fill out the components of the `pose.orientation` with the components of the quaternion.

A quick Google also found this which might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/shubh-agrawal/76754b9bfb0f4143819dbd146d15d4c8

**EDIT**

Since this became the accepted answer, I figured I'd post a little example of what I described. Something like the following should work:

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Vector3.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>

// Build identity rotation matrix as a cv::Mat
cv::Mat rot(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
cv::Rodrigues(cv::Vec3d({0.0, 0.0, 0.0}), rot);
// Convert to a tf2::Matrix3x3
tf2::Matrix3x3 tf2_rot(rot.at<double>(0, 0), rot.at<double>(0, 1), rot.at<double>(0, 2),
                       rot.at<double>(1, 0), rot.at<double>(1, 1), rot.at<double>(1, 2),
                       rot.at<double>(2, 0), rot.at<double>(2, 1), rot.at<double>(2, 2));
// Create a transform and convert to a Pose
tf2::Transform tf2_transform(tf2_rot, tf2::Vector3());
geometry_msgs::Pose pose_msg;
tf2::toMsg(tf2_transform, pose_msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elektron97](https://answers.ros.org/users/72984/elektron97/) on 2021-07-26**:
Is there a way to convert tf::Mtrix3x3 in cv::Mat?